# Insert line into a query result (sum)

Tags: sql, insert, sum

I have a report that shows products that customers have ordered, along with their prices:

```
CompanyA    Product 7    14.99  
CompanyA    Product 3    45.95
CompanyA    Product 4    12.00
CompanyB    Product 3    45.95
CompanyC    Product 7    14.99
CompanyC    Product 3    45.95
```

I'd like to insert a line that sums each company's order, like this:

```
CompanyA    Product 7    14.99  
CompanyA    Product 3    45.95
CompanyA    Product 4    12.00
               Total:    72.94
CompanyB    Product 3    45.95
               Total:    45.95
CompanyC    Product 7    14.99
CompanyC    Product 3    45.95
               Total:    60.94
```

Here's some code that shows the basic structure of the query I have:

```
SELECT company
   , product
   , price
FROM companyMaster
ORDER BY company,
   , product,
   , price;
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm writing this in Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's feedback/help, it at least got me thinking of different approaches. I came up with something that doesn't depend on what version of SQL Server I'm using (our vendor changes versions often so I have to be as cross-compliant as possible).

This might be considered a hack (ok, it is a hack) but it works, and it gets the job done:

```
SELECT company
   , product
   , price
FROM companyMaster
ORDER BY company,
   , product,
   , price

UNION

SELECT company + 'Total'
   , ''
   , SUM(price)
FROM companyMaster
GROUP BY company

ORDER BY company;
```

This solution basically uses the UNION of two select statements. The first is exactly like the orginal, the second produces the sum line I needed. In order to correctly locate the sum line, I did a string concatenation on the company name (appending the word 'Total'), so that when I sort alphabetically on company name, the Total row will show up at the bottom of each company section.

Here's what the final report looks like (not exactly what I wanted but functionally equivalent, just not very pretty to look at:

```
CompanyA    Product 7    14.99  
CompanyA    Product 3    45.95
CompanyA    Product 4    12.00
CompanyA Total           72.94
CompanyB    Product 3    45.95
CompanyB Total           45.95
CompanyC    Product 7    14.99
CompanyC    Product 3    45.95
CompanyC Total           60.94
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  company,
        product,
        SUM(price)
FROM    companyMaster
GROUP BY
        company, ROLLUP(product)
```

Comment: When I try this in Query Analyzer, I'm getting the following error (just to clarify, I'm using T-SQL): Server: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 59
'ROLLUP' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Looking online, it seems that the COMPUTE function may be backward compatible with the version of T-SQL I'm using. ROLLUP is only supported by Server 2005 and up.

Comment: @dvanaria - you need to specify what version you are using, then.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that - before now I didn't know how to check, but I looked it up and used the SELECT @@VERSION query to check: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86)   Nov 24 2008 13:01:59   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2) Now I don't know why that ROLLUP function wasn't recognized, it should be right?

Comment: +1 from me on this one. I just added the same answer with SQL Server 2005 syntax. BTW I stole the cte construct `select .. from( values ` from an earlier answer from you. Really nice.

Comment: @Mikael: you better put it back where you stole it since it does not work in `SQL Server 2005` :)

Comment: Of course. Changing compatibility level is not to be trusted to prevent you from using new fancy stuff in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on SQL Server 2005 you need to use [rollup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) like this.

```
-- cte for test data
;with companyMaster(company, product, price) as
(select 'CompanyA',    'Product 7',    14.99 union all  
 select 'CompanyA',    'Product 3',    45.95 union all
 select 'CompanyA',    'Product 4',    12.00 union all
 select 'CompanyB',    'Product 3',    45.95 union all
 select 'CompanyC',    'Product 7',    14.99 union all
 select 'CompanyC',    'Product 3',    45.95
)

select
  company,
  case when grouping(product) = 0
    then product
    else 'Total:'
  end,
  sum(price)
from companyMaster
group by company, product with rollup
having grouping(company) = 0
```