# Insert line into a query result (sum)

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert line into a query result (sum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719384/insert-line-into-a-query-result-sum)

I have a report that shows products that customers have ordered, along with their prices:

```
CompanyA    Product 7    14.99  
CompanyA    Product 3    45.95
CompanyA    Product 4    12.00
CompanyB    Product 3    45.95
CompanyC    Product 7    14.99
CompanyC    Product 3    45.95
```

I'd like to insert a line that sums each company's order, like this:

```
CompanyA    Product 7    14.99  
CompanyA    Product 3    45.95
CompanyA    Product 4    12.00
               Total:    72.94
CompanyB    Product 3    45.95
               Total:    45.95
CompanyC    Product 7    14.99
CompanyC    Product 3    45.95
               Total:    60.94
```

Here's some code that shows the basic structure of the query I have:

```
SELECT company
   , product
   , price
FROM companyMaster
ORDER BY company,
   , product,
   , price;
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm writing this in Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you using a report writer? This is something they make very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two queries with different "group by"  one is by customer, product and the other is by customer only.